# Reading csv from specific directory and insert it to custom post type (cron job)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-cron, csv

Need a comprehensive cron job script to read .csv data uploaded regularly to specific folder.

Will insert data to custom post type only if csv exist base on cron job current date.

Any suggestion of best script/plugin to read the csv?

The script output must be easily modified to be insert to custom post type.

Thanks. :-)

Comment: This [class](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/) works well

Comment: As the [help] states, plugin recommendations are out of scope. Please show us some of your code and research, as this is prerequisite for questions. Thanks.